# PHP: Get list of all filenames contained within my images directory

Tags: php

I have been trying to figure out a way to list all files contained within a directory.  I'm not quite good enough with php to solve it on my own so hopefully someone here can help me out.

I need a simple php script that will load all filenames contained within my images directory into an array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Try [glob](http://php.net/glob)

Something like:

```
 foreach(glob('./images/*.*') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }
```

Comment: How to get it with full path?

Comment: How can we get all files within list of extensions? E.g. if we want all .php and .js files ?

Comment: @Nis replace `glob('./images/*.*')` with `glob('./images/*.{php,js}', GLOB_BRACE)`

Comment: Nice Job, I was just playing around to do this ... php is awesome , thanks

Answer (score 20):

[`scandir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) - List files and directories inside the specified path

```php
$images = scandir("images", 1);
print_r($images);
```

Produces:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => apples.jpg
    [1] => oranges.png
    [2] => grapes.gif
    [3] => ..
    [4] => .
)
```

Comment: Do you know why scandir has two array keys that contain periods?  Seems kinda strange to me.

Comment: In brief, the periods are the standard directory annotators in Linux. The single period denotes the current directory and the double period denotes the parent directory.

Answer (score 14):

Either [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) as suggested elsewhere or

- [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) — Find pathnames matching a pattern

**Example**

```
$images = glob("./images/*.gif");
print_r($images);

/* outputs 
Array (
   [0] => 'an-image.gif' 
   [1] => 'another-image.gif'
)
*/
```

Or, to walk over the files in directory directly instead of getting an array, use

- [`DirectoryIterator` — provides a simple interface for viewing the contents of filesystem directories](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

**Example**

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $item) {
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
}
```

To go into subdirectories as well, use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php):

```
$items = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
}
```

To list just the filenames (w\out directories), remove `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST`

Comment: with GLOB if you have this error "PHP glob(): At least one of the passed flags is invalid or not supported on this platform in"   . Here is the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763115/php-glob-at-least-one-of-the-passed-flags-is-invalid-or-not-supported-on-this                   . **just in case**

Comment: @keke 1 corresponds to `GLOB_ERR`, which was added in PHP 5.1.0. If that causes an error, you are using an outdated PHP version. Consider updating it. Then again, it's always better to use the constant itself instead of it's value, so I should have used `GLOB_ERR` instead in the first place. I removed it from the answer now because it's not needed for the usecase at hand.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Standard PHP Library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)'s [`DirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class, specifically the `getFilename` method:

```
 $dir = new DirectoryIterator("/path/to/images");
 foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
      echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
 }
```

Comment: this also adds . and .. so not a good solution

Comment: also, it doesnt filter by extensions and will add you unnecessary files like .thumb

Answer (score 2):

This will gives you all the files in links.

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_folder/"; 

$files = scandir($path);
$count=1;
foreach ($files as $filename)
{
    if($filename=="." || $filename==".." || $filename=="download.php" || $filename=="index.php")
    {
        //this will not display specified files
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<label >".$count.".&nbsp;</label>";
        echo "<a href="download.php/?filename=".$filename."">".$filename."</a>
";
        $count++;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this function can be useful in the future. You can manipulate the function if you need to echo things or want to do other stuff.

```
$wavs = array();
$wavs = getAllFiles('folder_name',$wavs,'wav');

$allTypesOfFiles = array();
$wavs = getAllFiles('folder_name',$allTypesOfFiles);

//explanation of arguments from the getAllFiles() function
//$dir -> folder/directory you want to get all the files from.
//$allFiles -> to store all the files in and return in the and.
//$extension -> use this argument if you want to find specific files only, else keept empty to find all type of files.

function getAllFiles($dir,$allFiles,$extension = null){
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){           
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
            $allFiles = getAllFiles($dir.'/'.$file,$allFiles,$extension);
        }else{
            if(empty($extension) || $extension == pathinfo($dir.'/'.$file)['extension']){
                array_push($allFiles,$dir.'/'.$file);
            }
        }
    }
    return $allFiles;
}
```

Comment: This won't work, you should returning the recursive call, you will get an infinite loop otherwise