# how to read subfolders data in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP recursive directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398147/php-recursive-directory-path)
>   [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory)
>   [PHP: Get list of all filenames contained within my images directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059891/php-get-list-of-all-filenames-contained-within-my-images-directory)

I have a directory on the server which contains some sub folders. The sub folders contain  some pdf files. I need to display all sub folder names and sub folder data as well. Please guide me how to read data in subfolders.

here is my code

```
<?php
$number=$_REQUEST['Username'];
$folder=dir("UserIds/".$Username."/");
$i=0;
while($folderEntry=$folder->read())
{
if($folderEntry !=".." && $folderEntry !=".")
      {   
      $message[$i]="http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/UserIds/$number/".$folderEntry;
      $i++;
      }
  }
echo json_encode($message);
$folder->close();
?>
```

here  I am enter the directory name I need that particular directory data will display
please guide me

Thanks for advance...

Answer (score 2):

in recursive way.

```
$message=get_files("UserIds/".$Username);
function get_files($dir){
    $message=array();

    $folder=dir($dir);
    while($folderEntry=$folder->read())
    {
       if($folderEntry !=".." && $folderEntry !=".")
       {   

          $message[]="http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/".$dir."/".$folderEntry;
          if (is_dir($dir."/".$folderEntry)){
             $new_message=get_files($dir."/".$folderEntry);
             if (is_array($new_message)){
                 $message=array_merge($message,$new_message);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    $folder->close();
  return $message;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response I put your code i get this answer ["http:\/\/www.myappdemo.com\/appinstaller\/UserIds\/\/Winter.jpg"]  here after userId missing sub folder name
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/myappdemo/myappdemo.com/appinstaller/Directory.php on line 19
null

Comment: I edited my message to add if array and also correct the folder name, you probably need to change it to reflect the message you want to display. I only meant to post the idea.  also I'm not sure why you got array_merge problem did you post exactly or added new return? but anyway I put if is_array just in case

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your

```
while($folderEntry=$folder->read())
{
     if($folderEntry !=".." && $folderEntry !=".")
     {   
         $message[$i]="http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/UserIds/$number/".$folderEntry;
         $i++;
     } 
}
```

with

```
while (false !== ($folderEntry = $folder->read())) {
    if($folderEntry !=".." && $folderEntry !=".")
    {   
        $message[$i]="http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/UserIds/$number/".$folderEntry;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I think you're there.

And I can't see your setting $Username anywhere I reckon `$folder=dir("UserIds/".$Username."/");` should be `$folder=dir("UserIds/".$number."/");` as well.

Comment: ho..thanks for your response yes it's $number here i am username i get the directory data but i need also sub folders data also plz guide me how to get sub folders data

Comment: above code I get response is ["http:\/\/www.myappdemo.com\/appinstaller\/UserIds\/kumareawqwe\/2011-August-12"] here "2011-August-12" contains the sub folder i need sub folders data also plz tell how to get this

Comment: Sorry, I read your original message a bit to hasty. I would break the whole thing out to a recursive method that checks the $folderEntry with is_dir (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) to solve the subfolder part.

Answer (score -1):

Ever heard of recursivity? :)

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=71882