# Rename Duplicate file name to another name in multiple folders

Tags: java, php, python, bash, perl

I have 3 folders named like **FOLDER1**, **FOLDER2**, **FOLDER3** and I have couple of files in those folders like wise **file1.txt**, **file2.txt**, **file3.txt** .... etc. ( in those 3 folder don't have sub folders).

In those folders some files are duplicates.

`FOLDER1` has `file1.txt` and `FOLDER2` also has `file1.txt`

OR

`FOLDER2` has `file1.txt` and `FOLDER3` has `file1.txt`

OR

`FOLDER1` has `file1.txt` and `FOLDER3` has `file 1.txt`.

Need to rename another duplicate `file1.txt` in another folder as `file1DUPLICATE.txt`.

Suppose if `FOLDER1` and `FOLDER2` have `file1.txt`, I need to rename the `file1.txt` in the `FOLDER1` as `file1DUPLICATE.txt` and retain the `file1.txt` in the `FOLDER2` as original.

If duplicate occurs in `FOLDER1` and `FOLDER2` I need to rename in the `FOLDER1` only.

If Duplicate occurs in the `FOLDER2` and `FODLER3`, I need to rename in the `FOLDER3` only.

#### Simply I dont want to rename the files in the FOLDER2

If duplicate occurs in the `FOLDER1` and `FOLDER3`, I can rename the `file.txt` whichever folder I want.

Anyone have idea for implementing the script for that ?

Comment: if you are using php then use `scandir()` function to check the filenames

Comment: refer the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059891/php-get-list-of-all-filenames-contained-within-my-images-directory

Comment: The lack of code and array of tags you've chosen suggests that you're hoping someone will drop a complete program in your lap. Please take a [tour] of SO and learn [ask] good questions to find out why this question will almost certainly be downvoted and closed.

Comment: @phpjsnerd: If you want someone to do your work for you then please "passby". Your question isn't wanted here, as so many downvotes and close votes should tell you.

Comment: @phpjsnerd I'm afraid you are mistaken in your understanding of how SO works. There is an established set of rules and guidelines that everyone is expected to follow, and when people don't follow those rules, the community responds with downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @phpjsnerd Also, you mention someone with @, not #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show much effort to let us help you solving this. But since I'm learning bash scripting, I took your question as practicing.

So... here is a bash script to rename duplicated files.

/!\ The renamed files will be in the folder of first argument. So, in your case, you'll have to launch it like this :

- Rename duplicated files from folder1 and folder2 :

  `$ mv_duplicates_script.sh /path/to/FOLDER1 /path/to/FOLDER2`
- Rename duplicated files from folder1 and folder3 :

  `$ mv_duplicates_script.sh /path/to/FOLDER1 /path/to/FOLDER3`
- Rename duplicated files from folder3 and folder2 :

  `$ mv_duplicates_script.sh /path/to/FOLDER3 /path/to/FOLDER2`

Note that you have to set FOLDER2 at last argument for the renamed files go to FOLDER3.

```
#!/bin/bash

# if missing args, print Usage
##############################
if [[ -z $1 ]] || [[ -z $2 ]]
  then
    echo "Usage : `basename $0` /absolute/path/to/folder1 /absolute/path/to/folder2"

    # exit with failed status
    exit 1
fi

# test if folders exist
#######################
if [[ ! -d $1 ]]
  then
    echo "ERROR : Folder $1 not found..."

    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -d $2 ]]
  then
    echo "ERROR : Folder $2 not found..."

    exit 1
fi

# get filenames from folder 1
#############################

cd $1

i=0
for f in *.txt
  do
    folder1_files[$i]=$f
    ((i++))
done



# get filenames from folder 2
#############################

cd $2

i=0
for f in *.txt
  do
    folder2_files[$i]=$f
    ((i++))
done


# compare and move duplicates
#############################

for f in ${folder1_files[@]}
  do
    for g in ${folder2_files[@]}
      do
        if [[ $f == $g ]]
          then
            echo "Duplicate file : $g"
            echo "Renaiming to DUPLICATE_$g in $1"
            mv $1/$g $1/DUPLICATE_$g
        fi
    done
done

exit 0
```

Use it as :

**`$ mv_duplicates_script.sh /absolute/path/to/folder1 /absolute/path/to/folder2`**

Hope it helps.

PS : This can certainly be improved and your comments/tips are welcome.