# How use while loop image from the Directory inserting a record into Database in MYSQL Script

Tags: mysql

I am inserting an image from directory into Database:

Here's my attempt and this is working, but it only insert one record at a time:

```
insert into tbl_image(image) values(LOAD_FILE('E:/EDITED/Studio Session-012.jpg'))
```

I need to insert `all images` from edited folder together with each `image name`.

I am thinking that i need something like a `loop` to that folder so that i could get all images and insert into database.

Is this possible?

All Suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059891/php-get-list-of-all-filenames-contained-within-my-images-directory

Comment: I'd be sorely tempted to use a bit of application level code for this

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. @Bikash it is a PHP code.

Comment: Yes. You can loop for each images and insert into table

Comment: But i need MYSQL SCRIPT.